# Подключение файлов в C++

Tags: c++

Иногда работаю с IDE на Андроиде (в основном Dcoder). Как можно подключить (и можно ли вообще) заголовочный либо любой другой файл средствами языка, если нет возможности сделать через саму IDE (IDE такие программы можно назвать с большой натяжкой).
P.S. только учу плюсы, совсем зеленый

Comment: Гм... А `#include` - это не подключение заголовочного файла средствами языка? Ну, а "любого другого" - видимо, с помощью командной строки?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен..... какой любой другой? include может хоть pdf подставить....